# Separating UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource Causes No Data to Show

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My ViewController is getting way too big because of all the methods needed for UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource, so I refactored my code to a different file, but now the data doesn't show up anymore...

Here's my current implementation:

In MyViewController.swift

```
class SomeView: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     myDataSourceClass(tableView: myTableView)
  }
}
```

In MyNewDataSourceClass.swift

```
class myDataSourceClass: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  let stuff = [1, 2, 3]
  init(tableView: UITableView) {
        super.init()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
  }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "please show up"
        return cell!
  }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.stuff.count
  }
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's much easier to create an extension of `SomeView` in a separate file rather than a class. The reason for the failure is that you are initializing the datasource class but it gets deallocated immediately after `viewDidLoad` exits

Comment: Are you keeping that myDataSourceClass reference somewhere?

Comment: @orxelm I am unfortunately not... Where should I keep it and how should I use that reference?

Comment: @vadian That makes sense. I'll try to create an extension to see how it goes. Beside the fact that the View code doesn't get bloated, is there any other inherent benefits to creating an extension versus a class like I did?

Comment: @LongTran So that is your problem i guess. Try to add a strong reference to myDataSourceClass and check.
`var myDataSourceClass: MyDataSourceClass` below the myTableView @IBOutlet declaration.

Comment: A class is only useful if you reuse it for multiple view controllers. For a single view controller there is no benefit.

Comment: So creating an extension for `SomeView` in a separate file works! Now all of my tableView code are in this separate file. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

// you need to reload table after setting delegate and datasource

```
class SomeView: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myDataSourceClass(tableView: myTableView)
    myTableView.reloadData()
 }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before posting the question but I don't think that's where the problem is.

Comment: then check  self.stuff.count and also check connection of tableview with reference